# "Bad Gateway" when connecting to old IIS servers over SSL through NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, windows-server-2003, reverse-proxy, iis-6

I am trying to set up an NGINX server as a reverse proxy to make it possible to connect via TLS 1.2 to an old IIS server that is limited to TLS 1.0

Connection on port 80 works fine.  But I get `502 Bad Gateway` when I try to connect over https.    When I look at the NGINX error logs I see this line...

`*364 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream`

Below is the config I have for the reverse proxy. (Note, website url and public IP changed to preserve anonymity)

```
 server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.mywebsite.com;

        location /{
                proxy_set_header Host "www.mywebsite.com";
                proxy_pass http://192.168.201.235:80/; 
        }
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        server_name www.mywebsite.com;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/mywebsite.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/mywebsite.key";

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host "www.mywebsite.com";
                proxy_pass https://192.168.201.235:443/;
        }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to resolve the bad gateway issue while still connecting securely between the proxy and the target server?

I can connect to the IP address directly over HTTPS, and if I put in another SSL enabled website after `proxy_pass` it also works.

I have tried searching for an answer to this on google but none of the hits are so far similar enough to my situation to be helpful.

Comment: It’s likely inability to SSL handshake between proxy and 2k3 box.  You may have to try enabling different ciphersuites or SSL/TLS levels to find one that will work with older box, though I don’t know if it’s possible to configure internal/external connections differently to avoid  compromising security on external connections.  I’m pretty sure that Apache reverse proxy can do this but I’ve never used nginx.

Comment: Did you try to use `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1;`? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/

Comment: @LexLi that worked!   Thankyou.     If you add it as a reply I will accept it.

Comment: @MikaelH You are absolutely right, I should migrate/upgrade/solve this properly, but my hands are a bit tied and I at this stage I am merely seeing if it is at least possible to do this the cheap way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting `proxy_ssl_protocols` seems to control the connection between nginx and the upstream server (Windows Server 2003 in your case),

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/

Its default setting today might block TLS 1.0, so you need to set `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1;` to enable TLS 1.0.

Comment: Thankyou again.  This worked, and I am able to connect to the website externally over TLS 1.2.